Last $4$ nonzero digits of $n!$ in base fourteen
Question: What are the last $4$ nonzero digits of $2025!$ in base fourteen?
Note: This is not a contest/homework question.
I know how to find the number of trailing zeroes in base fourteen, so $2025!$ has:
$\lfloor{\frac{2025}{7}}\rfloor+\lfloor{\frac{2025}{7^{2}}}\rfloor+\lfloor{\frac{2025}{7^{3}}}\rfloor=289+41+5=335$ trailing zeroes.
But I was stucked here: Find the last $4$ nonzero digits of $2025!$ in base fourteen.
My instinct is to exclude all multiples of $7$ below or equal to $2025$ based on this answer, so all I have to do is to compute $(1\times2\times3\times4\times5\times6)(8\times9\times10\times11\times12\times13)\cdots(2017\times2018\times2019\times2020\times2021\times2022)(2024\times2025)\pmod{2401}$
to find the last $4$ nonzero digits of $2025!$ in base fourteen, as $2025!$ is certainly divisible by $16$, but I don't know how to continue.

Does the answer here help?

You need to compute the congruency class, $~\pmod{14^4}~$ of $~\dfrac{2025!}{14^{335}}.~$  Personally, I'm unsure how to do this.  My approach, which might well fail, would be to first compute the congruency class $~\pmod{14},~$ and then compute the congruency class $~\pmod{14^2},~$ and so forth.
